# what is .htaccess file for in Magento, is it important in anyway?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, .htaccess

I see this file in both Magento one and two, I would like to know what is its functionality in Magento because I have read some articles about it that explains that this .htaccess 

`"file is a configuration file that affects how a web server responds to various requests. It is supported by several web servers, including the popular Apache software used by most commercial web hosting providers."`

can Magento function without the file, any edit you can do for extra or advanced functionalities?

this is all I found in my Magento website.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Please check out the following article, it will help you
https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-htaccess/ 
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/magento/administration/use-htaccess/

Comment: Thanks, Wow seems like there is quite a lot one can do, using this file. blocking and giving access to some IP and users.

Comment: yes we can do lot of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess`-Files are used by apache-webserver to be able edit/extend the webserver-config as a "normal"-user.
I.e. you can do in this file much that would normally require editing the global configuration, however that is normally only editable as system-administrator.

Popular things that are often handled in .htaccess files:

- deny access to folders: like in your example (`Deny from all`), this denies access to the folder this file is in. F.e. include-files, classes, configs etc.
- route requests to front-controller to create nicer urls: to have urls like "/catalog/t-shirts/men/nice-shirt.html" instead of "index.php?action=view_product&category=4&product=234", there are normally "RewriteRule"-entries in the .htaccess to tell apache to go through the index.php-file, when a file/directory is not present in the filesystem

Comment: sounds interesting just for interest sake since I am also working on *wordpress*, does wordpress have this file as a protection for folders and stuff or I can just include it in my wordpress files?